# Solution for ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I work for advertising seo company. They have dedicated server and want also use SSL for the clients. They asked me to find the best option regarding that, I need help from you guys.  I suppose some of you are more experienced in this.

1. Should they buy certificates separately for each client?
2. Create self signed certificate (Is there any way avoid security warnings).
3. Use wild card or multiple domain SSL
4. Other option (please suggest)

Thanks

Comment: Have you heared about [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No. 3. Yes. 4. None. Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand using [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/).
It is free, you can do wildcard, automatic renewal every 3 month, documentation, etc. 
I'm a big fan of it.

You can also use your registrar, sometimes they also sell certificates for the domain they sell. Like [Gandi](https://www.gandi.net/fr) for example, you got 1 year free certificate with a domain, and they guide you all along on how to install it.